# .net(C#) Comparing two list of strings and removing non matching elements

Tags: c#

Is there any way to compare two list of strings(regardless of case sensitivity) or do I need to write custom code for such comparison? I also want to remove non-matching items from my dictionary.

e.g

```
List<string> lst1 = new List<string>();
lst1.Add("value1");
lst1.Add("VALUE2");

List<string> lst2 = new List<string>();
lst2.Add("value1");
lst2.Add("value2");
lst2.Add("value3");
```

Now after comparison I want to have only "value1" and "value2" in `lst2`.

Regards,
JS

Comment: Please fix your example, it should be lst1 and lst2

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use LINQ [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx) method.

```
var result = lst1.Intersect(lst2, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

You can avoid creating your own implementation of `IEqualityComparer<string>` by using [StringComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx)

If you want the result to be in the `lst2`, then do it like that:

```
lst2 = lst1.Intersect(lst2, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Enumerable.Intersect` method

Refer to the MSDN documentation for examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx

Refer to Dyppl's answer for implementing the Case insensitive comparison.

Comment: Nah, see my answer, you can use `StringComparer`

Comment: Thanks Dyppl! Updated the answer. That was really kool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Intersect` extension method. To do it case insenstive you can use an equaty comparer:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> lst1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> lst2 = new List<string>();

        CaseInsensitiveEquityComparer comparer = new CaseInsensitiveEquityComparer();

        var result = lst1.Intersect(lst2, comparer);

    }
}

class CaseInsensitiveEquityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return String.Compare(x,y,true,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) == 0;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparing strings by `ToUpper`-ing them? Bad idea in C#, just use `String.Compare` with corresponding options

Comment: @Dyppl, true - but was rushing. Fixed it up now ;)